# must drop fossil fuels, and fast

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "and fast" as "and act quickly."  Am I on the right track?

The phrase "fossil fuels, and fast" appears to be a typical alliteration, which explains why "fast" rather than "quick" is used.  I am not absolutely sure.

> The New York Times tweeted:

The world’s leading energy agency said nations **must drop fossil fuels, and fast**, if they want to avert catastrophic climate change.

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/nytimes/status/1394528198373871617)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The New York Times* tweeted:

> The world's leading energy agency said nations **must drop fossil
> fuels, and fast**, if...

What that means is:

> The world's leading energy agency said nations **must drop fossil fuels
> fast**, if...

*The New York Times* simply separated out the adverb "fast" with "and" and a pair of commas in order to add emphasis, in order to stress that doing so quickly is especially important.